# full-frame helm?

Tags: helm, window, frames

Is it possible to run something like `helm-recentf` or `helm-mini` in a way that the `helm` window occupies the entire frame when it's running, and then disappears afterwards (like the `helm` windows normally do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you use use this:

```lisp
    (setq helm-full-frame t)
```

The slightly longer answer is that I wanted to use `helm-mini` as a 'dashboard' sort of thing when I started up emacs.  To do that I used this function:

```lisp
    (defun helm-dashboard()
      (if (< (length command-line-args) 2)
        (let (
          (helm-full-frame-orig helm-full-frame)
          (helm-mini-default-sources-orig helm-mini-default-sources)
          )

          (setq helm-full-frame t)
          (setq helm-mini-default-sources
          `(helm-source-bookmarks helm-source-recentf))
          (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)
          (helm-mini)
          (setq helm-full-frame helm-full-frame-orig)
          (setq helm-mini-default-sources helm-mini-default-sources-orig))))
```

Then, in my `init.el` I added this as part of my helm config:

```lisp
    (add-hook 'window-setup-hook
        (lambda () (helm-dashboard)))
```

(I want this to run last, after the `emacs-startup-hook`)